# How to keep object values in a form when updating object angular 5+?

Tags: html, angular

I am using an expansion panel which I got from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples). I am using a loop to create each row and I would like for when the panel is expanded it shows the data from the current row to be edited. I am new to angular and what I have works, it updates the database. But what I have does not seems like the best solution because when the form opens it opens with the selected object data but as a place holder then the data becomes the label for the `Textbox` and the `Textbox` becomes empty. Is there a way to bind the current value to the Textbox value and not the placeholder and if I focus on the `Textbox` it keeps the text for me to edit.

Html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let search of searches">
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState2 = true" (closed)="panelOpenState2 = false">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <td><span class="badge">3</span></td>
    <td>{{ search.name }}</td>
    <td><button color="warn" (click)="deleteSearch(search._id)" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Del</button></td>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <td>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="{{ search.name }}" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" name="name" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" required>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
  <td><button (click)="updateSearch(search._id, inputValue)" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Edit</button></td>
</mat-expansion-panel>
</tr>
```

TypeScript Function:

```
updateSearch(id, name) {
    this.searchService.updateSearch(id,name,'dd')
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(name+ 'fjjf')
          console.log(res)
          this.fetchSearches();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `[(ngModel)]="search.name"` in your code.

Try the below code:-

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="search.name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also don't forget to update your `(click)` binder, something like below:-

```
(click)="updateSearch(search)"
```

And your typescript function could be updated as below:-

```
  updateSearch(search) {
    this.searchService.updateSearch(search._id, search.name, 'dd')
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(name+ 'fjjf')
          console.log(res)
          this.fetchSearches();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make only the value in the `Textbox` get updated until I hit the edit button(because I am using the same value for the label of the panel it updates live and if I collapse the panel it stays to the edited value)?

Comment: @Decoder94 Is there only one `inputValue` or multiple for each `search` row?

Comment: There are multiple searches, eg 4 rows, and if I click one the others collapse. if I open one I will be able to edit 'name' , 'type'... and other fields but because I use the name property as `mat-expansion-panel-header` if I open row 3 and edit it and collapse without clicking edit the `mat-expansion-panel-header` stays as the edited value.

Comment: @Decoder94 Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbkvux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts . It may help you on how to achieve what you need to do.